# PHP: Create a cron file in a directory owned by root? (Running as www-data)

Tags: php, bash, permissions, cron

I'm trying to add a new file to the `/etc/cron.d/` directory on my ubuntu server, so that a new cron script is added/run when a new user is added.  The user is created via a web UI, so the PHP code is executed by user `www-data`, but since the `/etc/cron.d/` directory is owned by `root` I cannot write there.

I do have control of the whole server, but I do not want to permanently change `/etc/cron.d/` to be owned by `www-data` for security reasons.

Ideally I'd like to do it all within a single PHP file, but I have tried using external bash scripts to navigate permissions, but without luck.  Essentially, this is what I'd like to make work:

```
$filename = "something.cron";
file_put_contents("/etc/cron.d/".$filename, "* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /another/file/to/execute.php");
```

What's the best way to go about this?  My apologies if it's been asked/answered already, I searched and found a dozen similar problems, but nothing quite matching and [since it's been over 30 minutes, I figured I could ask for help](https://xkcd.com/627/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Cron` job using `exec` command and can't set using `PHP`

```
exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n30 11 * * * /path/to/script" | crontab -');
```

This will run the script at 11:30 every day.

Check out this tutorial as well:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2--net-19428

Comment: On ubuntu I'm pretty sure you can just put a file in `/etc/cron.d/` and it will run on the schedule.  The file just reads like a single line from `crontab`

Comment: You need to basically edit the `crontab` file to add new entries for execution. Once you edit the file to enter your script name server will execute it automatically.